# Using Spotify API without manual authentication?

Tags: node.js, spotify

I'm trying to create a script to generate Spotify playlists with Node (using the spotify-web-api-node module), and I'm having problems getting authentication. I'm terrible with OAuth, so bear with me through this question.

If I understand correctly, I need to use the authorization code flow to get an access token, and to do it that way, I would need to visit a webpage to get the code. So my question is, is there any way to get the code without having to actually visit the webpage?

I tried using request to see if it would show a redirect, but it just shows me a website from Spotify. If I have to manually allow access to an account the first time, that's fine. I'm just trying to have to take away as much repetition as I can. Also, I'm trying to have this be specific to one account, if it could make a difference.